# Kubernetes-operator for creating statefulset replicas

Tags: kubernetes

I have a usecase where I have a custom statefulset, which I need to replicate as specified by the number by user, the same way deployment are scale up and down with replicas in kubernetes. And for that I am thinking about creating an kubernetes-operator e.g [memcached-operator](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk-samples/tree/master/memcached-operator), I need your suggestions, would it be right approach or anything simpler can be done to achieve this goal, and I need to manage those statefulsets as a single deployment or unit as per say.

for example this is what i want to achieve

`apiVersion: "sts.example.com/v1alpha1"
metadata:
...
units: 3
replicas: 2`

here units represent the number of `statefulsets` and replicas represents the number of `replicas` in each statefulset.

Comment: what component versions are you using?

Comment: I am using kubernetes 1.10 and go-lang 1.10.3

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean stating "I need to replicate as specified by the number by user". Is my understanding correct that you need to create as much statefulsets as the user will require? Why dont you want to change number of statefulsets instead of scaling up/down your replicas? Can you provide your entire yaml file?